# Convert Data url into image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using cordovaCamera plugin to get camera image.this method i got image as Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL (i.e Data.URL).Here i need to convert Data.URL into File object.I need to pass this file object into $http.post method.Any one give suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Append the DATA_URL with 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' in your camera;s success callback.

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(data) {
    var imgURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    convertToBlob(imgURI);
   }, function(err) {
});
```

**Step 2** 
Convert the data to a blob

```
function convertToBlob(imgData){
 var byteString = atob(imgData.split(',')[1]);
 var mimeString = imgData.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
 var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
 var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
   {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
   }
  return new Blob([ab], { 'type': mimeString });
}
```

**Step 3** 
 A blob is a file with no name. So just append that and you have a file

I guess you are using FormData to send the images to backend? If yes, then do this:

```
var fdata = new FormData();
// blob is the output from the convertToBlob method
fd.append('file', blob, 'a.jpg');
```

Comment: i already tried above method it's not working, finally i got exact answer. i am passing Data.URL directly into $http.post method.